# Checking if record matches another MS Access VBA/SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm not sure how to find a matching record via VBA. In the `SELECT` SQL it is selecting a record that matches the field of `program` and `language` from table CFRRR. In the `IF` statement I want to know if the selected record's `caseid` (which is also a field in CFRRR) matches the `casedid` of another record on CFRRR. I'm not sure if go the direction of DLookup or Match. Here is where I am at:

```
 strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [Program], [language] FROM CFRRR
 WHERE assignedto Is Null"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    If rs.currentrecord.caseid
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  If the recordset *rs* is empty, does that mean you've not found a match?  But if it's not empty, a match was found?

Comment: Hi @HansUp I edited my question. I had the wrong SQL there. rs would never be empty though. It will always have a selected record. I want to know if that selected record's `[caseid]` matches another record's `[caseid]` in table CFRRR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `SELECT`ing *CFRRRID* and you want to know whether that *CFRRRID* value is present in another row of the same table.  You can include a `DCount` expression to find out.

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [Program], [language], " & _
    "DCount('*', 'CFRRR', 'CFRRRID=' & CFRRRID) AS CountOfCFRRRID " & _
    "FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
```

When the calculated value, *CountOfCFRRRID*, is greater than 1, you know the current *CFRRRID* value is stored in another row of the table.

Comment: I don't know what you want from `rs.recordcount`.  But `rs!CountOfCFRRRID` will tell you whether the *CFRRRID* value from the current row exists in another row.